# Django Rest Framework: Validation not working when setting a "validator" inside the model field

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I created a simple model for Tasks, the "days" field is supposed to be a list of integers from 0 to 6 depending on the days of the week that the tasks is supposed to be done. For example Monday, Wednesday and Friday would be 1,3,5

```
class Task(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    time = models.TimeField()
    days = models.CharField(validators=[int_list_validator], max_length=16, blank=True)
```

The serializer looks like this:

```
class TaskCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ['name', 'time', 'days']
```

And the View looks like this:

```
class TaskCreateAPI(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = TaskCreateSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

When I do a POST request with some invalid data in the "days" field it will not raise any errors:

```
{
  "name": "Laundry",
  "time":"22:30",
  "days":"not an integer list"
}
```

How can I have the validation done for my API request? What is the point of adding the validation inside the model field if it's not being validated when I do a POST request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serializers take over validation from model forms as [explained in the documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#validation-in-rest-framework). Your validators would also not get called if you instantiate a model and save it, like is common in signal handlers and management commands. Model validators are only run when `ModelInstance.clean()` is called.

You should really ask yourself why you're storing arrays of integers in a char field. If you properly normalize this you can query for "all tasks on wednesday", which is a lot harder with denormalized fields like this.

```
class WeekDayChoices(IntegerChoices)
    monday = 0
    tuesday = 1
    wednesday = 2
    thursday = 3
    friday = 4
    saturday = 5
    sunday = 6

class WeekDay(models.Model):
    day = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=WeekDayChoices, primary_key=True)

class Task(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    time = models.TimeField()
    days = models.ManyToManyField(WeekDay, ...)

class WeekDaySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = WeekDay
        fields = ["day"]

class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    days = WeekDaySerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ['name', 'time', 'days']
```

Now you don't need a model validator, you can query days with tasks with ease and your `ModelSerializer` automatically accepts lists of integers as the only valid input.